# Flutter populating a list from a manually included database

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, assets

I want to read from an already existing database which I have included in my asset. But I keep getting No such table found. I tried the code from https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md

Comment: Can you add the code of what you have implemented in your application?

Comment: yeah, that would be helpful

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/53126885/flutter-sqflite-open-existing-database

Got the solution here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stackoverflow.com/questions/53126885/flutter-sqflite-open-existing-database

Got the answer from here